# Samsung Galaxy S6 edge unable to register on the network

Tags: android, networking, sim-card

I am in deep trouble right now and I don't know what is the problem. I purchased Galaxy S6 edge. 
It was not new but used and I got it for $450. 
I purchased it in a hurry. 
It was rooted and it was running with EE apps. 
I assume it is from EE. But it was working fine even with 4G. I wanted to upgrade it to marshmallow. 
When I unroot it and upgraded to Marshmallow it stopped registering my phone on the network. I am in Pakistan and I purchased the phone from here.

Everything is working fine with the phone WIFI, Mobile Hotspot etc. 
But the only problem is that it is not registering the network. 
Sim is being read by the phone and it searches all the available network but couldn't register.

I downgraded the phone to lollipop and made the configuration just like it was before. 
I again rooted the device so that it may work again. 
But it was of no use. 
I have been struggling to make it work for the past 4 days..

I have flashed modem.bin file of different carriers as well and tried to get that working but it doesn't work.

Please help me with that.. Any response will be very much appreciated.

Regards....

Comment: Please Insert your USIM/SIM card inside another handset and check if it register to the network or not? I guess something is wrong with the USIM/SIM card not the handset.

Answer (score 0):

If your SIM card works fine in another handset (i.e. registers to the network) and if you have tested another new sim in your S6 edge unsuccessfully. The Issue is that your Network Operator is blocking your Authentication based on your devices IMEI (Unique number identifying the device). This happens when the IMEI was blacklisted due to theft or some reason by the operator.

I assume that when you re-flashed you may have reset your IMEI to something that is blacklisted. Make sure the IMEI is the same as on the phone sticker normally under the battery.